# Duplicates when using inner join in t-sql

Tags: sql-server

I know i am missing something ,my issue is, I have two tables with identical values except a filter and trying to join these temp tables in a SP but i am getting duplicate values.
Below is the sample code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
B.SUBSCRIBER_TAX_ID, B.MEMBER_FIRST_NAME, B.MEMBER_LAST_NAME, 
B.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME AS MEDICAL_PLAN, B.MEMBER_EFF_DATE AS MED_EFF_DATE, B.MEMBER_TERMINATION_DATE AS MED_END_DATE,
P.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME AS PHARM_PLAN_NAME, P.MEMBER_EFF_DATE AS PHARM_EFF_DATE, P.MEMBER_TERMINATION_DATE AS PHARM_ENDdATE
FROM #BH_MED B
INNER JOIN #BH_PHARM P ON B.MEMBER_HCC_ID = P.MEMBER_HCC_ID
order by b.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME,P.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME
```

I want results as

![I want distinct abc,def in column 3 and column 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxWuH.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Please be more specific. The code posted works fine and returns what's in the tables with no dups (except it should be order by B.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME instead of b.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME. If you are getting dups it is because there are dups in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use group by

```
SELECT DISTINCT
B.SUBSCRIBER_TAX_ID, B.MEMBER_FIRST_NAME, B.MEMBER_LAST_NAME, 
B.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME AS MEDICAL_PLAN, B.MEMBER_EFF_DATE AS MED_EFF_DATE, B.MEMBER_TERMINATION_DATE AS MED_END_DATE,
P.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME AS PHARM_PLAN_NAME, P.MEMBER_EFF_DATE AS PHARM_EFF_DATE, P.MEMBER_TERMINATION_DATE AS PHARM_ENDdATE

FROM #BH_MED B
INNER JOIN #BH_PHARM P ON B.MEMBER_HCC_ID = P.MEMBER_HCC_ID

GROUP BY B.SUBSCRIBER_TAX_ID, B.MEMBER_FIRST_NAME, B.MEMBER_LAST_NAME,B.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME,B.MEMBER_EFF_DATE,B.MEMBER_TERMINATION_DATE,P.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME,P.MEMBER_EFF_DATE,P.MEMBER_TERMINATION_DATE

order by b.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME,P.BENEFIT_PLAN_NAME
```